# X server periodically restarting for no reason

Tags: xorg, crash

The following is for an Debian 7.x (wheezy) amd64 machine - my personal workstation.

X has been periodically restarting for no reason. It has been happening once a week or a bit less frequently. Recently it has seemed to be happening more recently. It just happened again just now. It might be the video card, which is quite old, or it might be  software problems. It would be helpful to at least figure out which category (hardware or software problem) this belongs to.

The current `/var/log/kdm.log` is below. I have also pasted `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` below that. If there is any other piece of information anyone wants me to provide, let me know.

`/var/log/kdm.log` output:

```
Backtrace:
0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x36) [0x7fe782e0f256]
1: /usr/bin/X (0x7fe782c90000+0x182da9) [0x7fe782e12da9]
2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7fe781fa0000+0xf0a0) [0x7fe781faf0a0]
3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so (0x7fe77b6d0000+0x54019c) [0x7fe77bc1019c]
4: /usr/bin/X (0x7fe782c90000+0x111031) [0x7fe782da1031]
5: /usr/bin/X (0x7fe782c90000+0x10a216) [0x7fe782d9a216]
6: /usr/bin/X (0x7fe782c90000+0x52f51) [0x7fe782ce2f51]
7: /usr/bin/X (0x7fe782c90000+0x41ec5) [0x7fe782cd1ec5]
8: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x7fe780caeead]
9: /usr/bin/X (0x7fe782c90000+0x4219d) [0x7fe782cd219d]

Segmentation fault at address 0x48

Fatal server error:
Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting


Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.

Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.

X.Org X Server 1.12.4
Release Date: 2012-08-27
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.16-2-amd64 x86_64 Debian
Current Operating System: Linux orwell 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.63-2+deb7u2 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/debian-root ro quiet
Build Date: 09 December 2014  09:12:48PM
xorg-server 2:1.12.4-6+deb7u5 (Moritz Muehlenhoff <jmm@debian.org>) 
Current version of pixman: 0.26.0
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Jan  5 18:57:02 2015
(==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
klauncher(14633) kdemain: No DBUS session-bus found. Check if you have started the DBUS server. 
kdeinit4: Communication error with launcher. Exiting!
kdmgreet(14625)/kdecore (K*TimeZone*): KSystemTimeZones: ktimezoned initialize() D-Bus call failed:  "Not connected to D-Bus server" 

kdmgreet(14625)/kdecore (K*TimeZone*): No time zone information obtained from ktimezoned
```

Here is `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old`:

```
[1971670.892] 
X.Org X Server 1.12.4
Release Date: 2012-08-27
[1971670.892] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[1971670.892] Build Operating System: Linux 3.16-2-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[1971670.892] Current Operating System: Linux orwell 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.63-2+deb7u2 x86_64
[1971670.892] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/debian-root ro quiet
[1971670.892] Build Date: 09 December 2014  09:12:48PM
[1971670.892] xorg-server 2:1.12.4-6+deb7u5 (Moritz Muehlenhoff <jmm@debian.org>) 
 ...
[1971670.892] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[1971670.892] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sun Jan  4 15:02:05 2015
[1971670.892] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[1971670.892] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[1971670.979] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[1971670.979] (**) |-->Screen "My Screens" (0)
[1971670.979] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[1971670.979] (==) No device specified for screen "My Screens".
    Using the first device section listed.
[1971670.979] (**) |   |-->Device "nVidia Corporation G70 [GeForce 7300 GS]"
...
[1971670.979] (==) Automatically adding devices
[1971670.979] (==) Automatically enabling devices
...
[1971670.980] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[1971670.980] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[1971670.980] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[1971670.980] (II) Loader magic: 0x7fe783079ae0
[1971670.980] (II) Module ABI versions:
[1971670.980]   X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[1971670.980]   X.Org Video Driver: 12.1
[1971670.980]   X.Org XInput driver : 16.0
[1971670.980]   X.Org Server Extension : 6.0
[1971670.980] (--) PCI:*(0:7:0:0) 10de:01d3:0000:0000 rev 161, Mem @ 0xfd000000/16777216, 0xd0000000/268435456, 0xfc000000/16777216, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[1971670.981] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[1971670.981] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
[1971670.981] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
[1971671.104] (II) Module extmod: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[1971671.104]   compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.0.0
[1971671.104]   Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[1971671.104]   ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[1971671.104] (II) Loading extension SELinux
[1971671.104] (II) Loading extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[1971671.104] (II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[1971671.105] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DGA
[1971671.105] (II) Loading extension DPMS
[1971671.105] (II) Loading extension XVideo
[1971671.105] (II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[1971671.105] (II) Loading extension X-Resource
[1971671.105] (II) LoadModule: "dbe"
[1971671.105] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdbe.so
[1971671.277] (II) Module dbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[1971671.277]   compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.0.0
[1971671.277]   Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[1971671.277]   ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[1971671.277] (II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[1971671.277] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[1971671.277] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/linux/libglx.so
[1971671.516] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[1971671.516]   compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[1971671.516]   Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[1971671.516] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  304.117  Tue Nov 26 21:45:09 PST 2013
[1971671.516] (II) Loading extension GLX
[1971671.516] (II) LoadModule: "record"
[1971671.517] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/librecord.so
[1971671.517] (II) Module record: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[1971671.517]   compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.13.0
[1971671.517]   Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[1971671.517]   ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[1971671.517] (II) Loading extension RECORD
[1971671.517] (II) LoadModule: "dri"
[1971671.517] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
[1971671.525] (II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[1971671.525]   compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.0.0
[1971671.525]   ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[1971671.525] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
[1971671.525] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[1971671.525] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[1971671.525] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[1971671.525]   compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.2.0
[1971671.525]   ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[1971671.525] (II) Loading extension DRI2
[1971671.525] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[1971671.525] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[1971671.568] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[1971671.568]   compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[1971671.568]   Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[1971671.578] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  304.117  Tue Nov 26 21:27:08 PST 2013
[1971671.578] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[1971671.578] (++) using VT number 7

[1971671.585] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[1971671.585] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[1971671.585] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[1971671.593] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[1971671.593]   compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.0.0
[1971671.593]   ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[1971671.593] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[1971671.593] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[1971671.593] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[1971671.628] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[1971671.628]   compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.0.0
[1971671.628]   ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[1971671.628] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[1971671.628] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[1971671.628] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[1971671.629] (II) NVIDIA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "My Screens" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[1971671.629] (==) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[1971671.629] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[1971671.629] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[1971671.629] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[1971671.629] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "MetaModes" "1280x1024, 1920x1200"
[1971671.629] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[1971671.751] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Sony SDM-HX93 (CRT-0)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[1971671.751] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Vision stereo.
[1971671.781] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (PCA DS-263N (CRT-1)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[1971671.781] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Vision stereo.
[1971671.784] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce 7300 SE/7200 GS (G72) at PCI:7:0:0 (GPU-0)
[1971671.784] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 524288 kBytes
[1971671.784] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 05.72.22.76.00
[1971671.784] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[1971671.784] (--) NVIDIA(0): Interlaced video modes are supported on this GPU
[1971671.784] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GeForce 7300 SE/7200 GS at PCI:7:0:0
[1971671.784] (--) NVIDIA(0):     Sony SDM-HX93 (CRT-0) (connected)
[1971671.784] (--) NVIDIA(0):     PCA DS-263N (CRT-1) (connected)
[1971671.784] (--) NVIDIA(0):     TV-0
[1971671.784] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-0
[1971671.784] (--) NVIDIA(0): Sony SDM-HX93 (CRT-0): 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[1971671.784] (--) NVIDIA(0): PCA DS-263N (CRT-1): 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[1971671.784] (--) NVIDIA(0): TV-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[1971671.784] (--) NVIDIA(0): TV encoder: Unknown
[1971671.784] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-0: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[1971671.784] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-0: Internal Single Link TMDS
[1971671.784] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[1971671.784] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device Sony SDM-HX93 (CRT-0) (Using EDID frequencies has
[1971671.784] (**) NVIDIA(0):     been enabled on all display devices.)
[1971671.784] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[1971671.784] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device PCA DS-263N (CRT-1) (Using EDID frequencies has
[1971671.784] (**) NVIDIA(0):     been enabled on all display devices.)
[1971671.784] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[1971671.784] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "1280x1024,1920x1200"
[1971671.784] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 3200 x 1200
[1971671.785] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to support custom viewPortOut 1280 x 720 +0 +152
[1971671.785] (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (85, 86); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
[1971671.785] (--) NVIDIA(0):     option
[1971671.785] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[1971671.792] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "1280x1024,1920x1200"
[1971671.940] (II) Loading extension NV-GLX
[1971671.960] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[1971671.960] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store disabled
[1971671.960] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[1971671.960] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[1971671.960] (II) Loading extension NV-CONTROL
[1971671.960] (II) Loading extension XINERAMA
[1971671.960] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Option "TwinView" is not used
[1971671.960] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[1971671.960] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[1971671.961] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[1971671.961] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[1971671.961]   compiled for 1.12.4, module version = 1.2.0
[1971671.961]   ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[1971671.961] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[1971671.961] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[1971671.961] (--) RandR disabled
[1971671.961] (II) Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[1971671.961] (II) Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[1971671.961] (II) Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[1971671.961] (II) Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[1971671.961] (II) Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[1971671.961] (II) Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[1971671.961] (II) Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[1971671.961] (II) Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[1971671.961] (II) Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[1971671.961] (II) Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[1971671.961] (II) Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[1971671.961] (II) Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[1971671.961] (II) Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[1971671.961] (II) Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[1971671.961] (II) Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[1971671.961] (II) Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[1971671.961] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[1971671.963] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[1971672.538] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event4)
[1971672.538] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[1971672.538] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[1971672.538] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[1971672.538] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[1971672.538]   compiled for 1.12.1, module version = 2.7.0
[1971672.538]   Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[1971672.538]   ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 16.0
[1971672.538] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[1971672.538] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[1971672.538] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event4"
[1971672.538] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[1971672.538] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[1971672.538] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[1971672.539] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input4/event4"
[1971672.539] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[1971672.539] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[1971672.539] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[1971672.539] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[1971672.539] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event3)
[1971672.539] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[1971672.539] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[1971672.539] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[1971672.539] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[1971672.539] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[1971672.539] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[1971672.539] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[1971672.539] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input3/event3"
[1971672.539] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[1971672.539] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[1971672.539] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[1971672.539] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[1971672.539] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Keyboard (/dev/input/event0)
[1971672.539] (**) Logitech USB Keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[1971672.539] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Logitech USB Keyboard'
[1971672.539] (**) Logitech USB Keyboard: always reports core events
[1971672.539] (**) evdev: Logitech USB Keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event0"
[1971672.539] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Keyboard: Vendor 0x46d Product 0xc31c
[1971672.539] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Keyboard: Found keys
[1971672.539] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[1971672.539] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/input/input0/event0"
[1971672.539] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech USB Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[1971672.539] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[1971672.539] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[1971672.539] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[1971672.540] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Keyboard (/dev/input/event1)
[1971672.540] (**) Logitech USB Keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[1971672.540] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Logitech USB Keyboard'
[1971672.540] (**) Logitech USB Keyboard: always reports core events
[1971672.540] (**) evdev: Logitech USB Keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[1971672.540] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Keyboard: Vendor 0x46d Product 0xc31c
[1971672.540] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Keyboard: Found absolute axes
[1971672.540] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Keyboard: Forcing absolute x/y axes to exist.
[1971672.540] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Keyboard: Found keys
[1971672.540] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Keyboard: Configuring as mouse
[1971672.540] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[1971672.540] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/input/input1/event1"
[1971672.540] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech USB Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[1971672.540] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[1971672.540] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[1971672.540] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[1971672.540] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Keyboard: initialized for absolute axes.
[1971672.540] (**) Logitech USB Keyboard: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[1971672.540] (**) Logitech USB Keyboard: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[1971672.540] (**) Logitech USB Keyboard: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[1971672.540] (**) Logitech USB Keyboard: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[1971672.540] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse (/dev/input/event2)
[1971672.540] (**) Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[1971672.540] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse'
[1971672.540] (**) Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: always reports core events
[1971672.540] (**) evdev: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[1971672.541] (--) evdev: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: Vendor 0x46d Product 0xc025
[1971672.541] (--) evdev: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: Found 12 mouse buttons
[1971672.541] (--) evdev: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: Found scroll wheel(s)
[1971672.541] (--) evdev: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: Found relative axes
[1971672.541] (--) evdev: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: Found x and y relative axes
[1971672.541] (II) evdev: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: Configuring as mouse
[1971672.541] (II) evdev: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: Adding scrollwheel support
[1971672.541] (**) evdev: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[1971672.541] (**) evdev: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[1971672.541] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.0/input/input2/event2"
[1971672.541] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 10)
[1971672.541] (II) evdev: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: initialized for relative axes.
[1971672.541] (**) Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[1971672.541] (**) Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[1971672.541] (**) Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[1971672.541] (**) Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[1971672.541] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
[1971672.541] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[1971672.541] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[1971672.541] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Eee PC WMI hotkeys (/dev/input/event6)
[1971672.541] (**) Eee PC WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[1971672.541] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Eee PC WMI hotkeys'
[1971672.541] (**) Eee PC WMI hotkeys: always reports core events
[1971672.541] (**) evdev: Eee PC WMI hotkeys: Device: "/dev/input/event6"
[1971672.541] (--) evdev: Eee PC WMI hotkeys: Vendor 0 Product 0
[1971672.541] (--) evdev: Eee PC WMI hotkeys: Found keys
[1971672.541] (II) evdev: Eee PC WMI hotkeys: Configuring as keyboard
[1971672.541] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/eeepc-wmi/input/input6/event6"
[1971672.541] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Eee PC WMI hotkeys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[1971672.541] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[1971672.541] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[1971672.541] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[1971672.541] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PC Speaker (/dev/input/event5)
[1971672.542] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[1971672.542] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[1971691.269] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[1971691.387] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "1280x1024,1920x1200"
[1971714.413] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Sony SDM-HX93 (CRT-0)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[1971714.413] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Vision stereo.
[1971714.413] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[1971714.413] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device Sony SDM-HX93 (CRT-0) (Using EDID frequencies has
[1971714.414] (**) NVIDIA(0):     been enabled on all display devices.)
[1971714.445] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (PCA DS-263N (CRT-1)) does not support NVIDIA 3D
[1971714.445] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     Vision stereo.
[1971714.445] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[1971714.445] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device PCA DS-263N (CRT-1) (Using EDID frequencies has
[1971714.445] (**) NVIDIA(0):     been enabled on all display devices.)
[1992824.360] [mi] EQ overflowing.  Additional events will be discarded until existing events are processed.
[1992824.360] 
[1992824.360] Backtrace:
[1992824.379] 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x36) [0x7fe782e0f256]
[1992824.379] 1: /usr/bin/X (mieqEnqueue+0x26b) [0x7fe782df047b]
[1992824.379] 2: /usr/bin/X (0x7fe782c90000+0x66a02) [0x7fe782cf6a02]
[1992824.379] 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0x7fe779c78000+0x55d8) [0x7fe779c7d5d8]
[1992824.380] 4: /usr/bin/X (0x7fe782c90000+0x8dac7) [0x7fe782d1dac7]
[1992824.380] 5: /usr/bin/X (0x7fe782c90000+0xb1d98) [0x7fe782d41d98]
[1992824.380] 6: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7fe781fa0000+0xf0a0) [0x7fe781faf0a0]
[1992824.380] 7: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x7fe781d18000+0x6e794) [0x7fe781d86794]
[1992824.380] 8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (pixman_image_composite32+0x3d6) [0x7fe781d22666]
[1992824.380] 9: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so (fbComposite+0x1d8) [0x7fe77b4bfb38]
[1992824.380] 10: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so (0x7fe77b6d0000+0x53c067) [0x7fe77bc0c067]
[1992824.380] 11: /usr/bin/X (0x7fe782c90000+0x110da9) [0x7fe782da0da9]
[1992824.380] 12: /usr/bin/X (0x7fe782c90000+0xd9ae5) [0x7fe782d69ae5]
[1992824.380] 13: /usr/bin/X (0x7fe782c90000+0xdae3f) [0x7fe782d6ae3f]
[1992824.380] 14: /usr/bin/X (0x7fe782c90000+0xd7fac) [0x7fe782d67fac]
[1992824.380] 15: /usr/bin/X (ConfigureWindow+0x378) [0x7fe782d0c058]
[1992824.380] 16: /usr/bin/X (0x7fe782c90000+0x4d904) [0x7fe782cdd904]
[1992824.380] 17: /usr/bin/X (0x7fe782c90000+0x52f51) [0x7fe782ce2f51]
[1992824.380] 18: /usr/bin/X (0x7fe782c90000+0x41ec5) [0x7fe782cd1ec5]
[1992824.380] 19: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x7fe780caeead]
[1992824.380] 20: /usr/bin/X (0x7fe782c90000+0x4219d) [0x7fe782cd219d]
[1992824.380] 
[1992824.380] [mi] These backtraces from mieqEnqueue may point to a culprit higher up the stack.
[1992824.380] [mi] mieq is *NOT* the cause.  It is a victim.
[1992824.761] [mi] Increasing EQ size to 512 to prevent dropped events.
[1992824.761] [mi] EQ processing has resumed after 13 dropped events.
[1992824.761] [mi] This may be caused my a misbehaving driver monopolizing the server's resources.
[2072167.620] 
[2072167.620] Backtrace:
[2072167.620] 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x36) [0x7fe782e0f256]
[2072167.621] 1: /usr/bin/X (0x7fe782c90000+0x182da9) [0x7fe782e12da9]
[2072167.621] 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7fe781fa0000+0xf0a0) [0x7fe781faf0a0]
[2072167.621] 3: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so (0x7fe77b6d0000+0x54019c) [0x7fe77bc1019c]
[2072167.621] 4: /usr/bin/X (0x7fe782c90000+0x111031) [0x7fe782da1031]
[2072167.621] 5: /usr/bin/X (0x7fe782c90000+0x10a216) [0x7fe782d9a216]
[2072167.621] 6: /usr/bin/X (0x7fe782c90000+0x52f51) [0x7fe782ce2f51]
[2072167.621] 7: /usr/bin/X (0x7fe782c90000+0x41ec5) [0x7fe782cd1ec5]
[2072167.621] 8: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x7fe780caeead]
[2072167.621] 9: /usr/bin/X (0x7fe782c90000+0x4219d) [0x7fe782cd219d]
[2072167.621] 
[2072167.621] Segmentation fault at address 0x48
[2072167.621] 
Fatal server error:
[2072167.621] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[2072167.621] 
[2072167.621] 
...
[2072167.656] (II) evdev: Power Button: Close
[2072167.656] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[2072167.656] (II) evdev: Power Button: Close
[2072167.656] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[2072167.657] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Keyboard: Close
[2072167.657] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[2072167.657] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Keyboard: Close
[2072167.657] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[2072167.665] (II) evdev: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse: Close
[2072167.665] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[2072167.672] (II) evdev: Eee PC WMI hotkeys: Close
[2072167.672] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[2072168.213] Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

UPDATE 4th June 2015: This was happening with Debian wheezy (7.x); it is still happening with Debian jessie (8.x).

I'm running an Nvidia card with the nvidia proprietary driver.

```
inxi -G

Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA G72 [GeForce 7300 GS]
           Display Server: X.Org 1.16.4 driver: nvidia Resolution: 1280x1024@60.02hz, 1920x1200@59.88hz
           GLX Renderer: GeForce 7300 GS/PCIe/SSE2 GLX Version: 2.1.2 NVIDIA 304.125
```

Comment: I would suggest a memtest. I know I am pointing you in a different direction, but I had a similar issue ending with bad RAM. It baffled me to find that the Video was not the issue even though many many things suggested it.

Comment: @JustinEdmands yes, that sounds like a good idea. do you recommend memtest86?

Comment: yep memtest86 would be a good starting point. You can get memtest86 by itself or download the Ultimate Boot CD (UBCD) which includes memtest and quite a few other hardware testing utilities.